# Is my ChangeCalculator done right?

Tags: c#, .net, solid-principles

I'm doing some exercises in OOP and I just created a program that calculates amounts of denominations in a change at the shop. So, let's say something costs 10, I give 25.30 (for some reason), so I should get as a change: one 10, one 5, one 0.20, one 0.10.

My program consists of:

- IChangeCalculator - represents change calculator
- ChangeCalculatorPLN - implementation that returns MoneyAmountPLN (money denominations amounts in PLN currency)
- IMoneyAmount - represents data about amounts of denominations
- MoneyAmountPLN - represents money denominations amounts in PLN
- IMoneyToCoinsConverter - represents converter that converts given money to something that implements IMoneyAmount
- MoneyToCoinsConverterPLN - converts given amount of money to MoneyAmountPLN

Here is the source code:

```
public interface IChangeCalculator<T> where T : IMoneyAmount
{
    T Calculate(decimal price, decimal payedAmount);
}

public class ChangeCalculatorPLN : IChangeCalculator<MoneyAmountPLN>
{
    IMoneyToCoinsConverter<MoneyAmountPLN> _moneyToCoinsConverter;

    public ChangeCalculatorPLN( IMoneyToCoinsConverter<MoneyAmountPLN> moneyToCoinsConverter )
    {
        _moneyToCoinsConverter = moneyToCoinsConverter;
    }

    public MoneyAmountPLN Calculate(decimal price, decimal payedAmount)
    {
        var change = payedAmount - price;
        if (change < 0)
            throw new Exception("The given amount of money is not enough!");
        if (change == 0)
            return MoneyAmountPLN.Empty;

        var amount = GetAmount(change);
        return amount;
    }

    private MoneyAmountPLN GetAmount(decimal change)
    {
        return _moneyToCoinsConverter.Convert(change);
    }
}

public interface IMoneyAmount
{
    IEnumerable<int> GetAmounts( );
}

//MoneyAmountPLN is quite long, because it contains fields for each denomination: 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01. I'll not put it here.

public interface IMoneyToCoinsConverter<T> where T : IMoneyAmount
{
    T Convert(decimal money);
}

public class MoneyToCoinsConverterPLN : IMoneyToCoinsConverter<MoneyAmountPLN>
{
    public MoneyAmountPLN Convert(decimal money)
    {
        //logic doesn't really matter here. It returns MoneyAmountPLN with corrects amounts of denominations.
    }

}
```

The program works, I did some unit tests. My real issue is that I'm not sure if this implementation is a good one. Did I do some mistakes? Could some parts be done better? Personally I think that maybe the structure is a little too complicated? If I saw a program like this for the first time, I would probably feel lost, but I'm not a very good programmer, so I can't say if my feeling is right.

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is a good place for such question, if it is, I'm asking for advices from more experienced developers than I am.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: also looks over engineered for what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim, OP _doing some exercises in OOP_ - so it is exactly right place to do over engineering. And statement _looks over engineered_ - is not very useful for OP or others ;)

Comment: As @CamiloTerevinto correctly pointed out your question belongs to CodeReview stack. To get useful codereview, please provide examples of how and where your classes will be used

Comment: @Fabio there is never an excuse for over engineering. OOP has nothing to do with excessive engineering. Good software design always keeps things as simple as possible. I'm sure the poster will receive good feedback in the CodeReview stack.

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim, the problem is that without doing over engineered staff you will not be able to draw a line between simple or over engineered. Unless you always write simple `if .. else` everywhere then your code will be always simple ;)

Comment: @Fabio maybe. I don't think many people would agree it is readily clear what the logic in this code is doing. All I see is the use of several classes and generics, whereas the requirements are exceedingly simple. if..else.. would have indeed been a better design than what's posted above. Having said this, I respect that everyone has their own opinion and approach towards software design.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about Code Review existence, thanks for enlightening me. Already your feedback is helpful, thanks a lot for that. Personally I also feel that the code is a bit over engineered and it could be simplified while providing the same value, especially extensibility. The new link (at Code Review) is here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202502/changecalculator-for-calculating-money-denominations-in-change

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Code Review SE and Loreno (OP) re-asked there.

Comment: @NikhilVartak [it doesn't appear Loreno has asked on CR since 2016](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/123219/loreno)... did you mean OP should re-ask there (not past-tense)?

Comment: @AndrewElliott please see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202502/changecalculator-for-calculating-money-denominations-in-change). There's definitely some glitch in profile data.

Comment: @NikhilVartak Yes [this Loreno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6886682/loreno) !== [this Loreno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5021151/loreno) though it could be the same owner...